# What is the closest alternative to SQLite database in terms of supported functions and datatypes?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, oracle11g, rdbms

I have a system where we generate 'physical sql' targeting the different database for a 'logical sql'. We have a bunch of supported DBs where the physical sql is supported (Oracle, MySql, Postgres etc). I am adding SQLite as a new DB to be supported but we can reuse the physical sql generator. I guess my question is which generator would generate a sql which is closer to SQlite. Couple of options that I can think is either MYSQL or ORACLE DB.

Comment: Yes, MySQL has some similarities to SQLite.  Best practice for _all_ of your database code would be to adhere to the ANSI SQL standard as closely as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Will try to update this thread if I find anything glaringly incompatible!

Comment: SQLite sometimes uses PostgreSQL for inspiration, e.g. [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html)